# Updating a class in an ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, class, code-behind

I have a certain class in VB in my `App_Code` folder, I can't deploy it directly to the website because I have no permission to the FTP, and I was asked to change a certain VB.net class and send it so someone would replace it in the FTP folder.

What happens is: there is no `App_Code` folder in the FTP folder. and the class generates **NO DLL** to be sent and replace it in the bin folder (which exists).

Aditionally: The website deploys and runs normally in the localhost (and i can see it in the browser), but there is no data from the website in the c:\inetpub\wwwroot. nor anywhere else, where are de website files ?

Which file, or how could I send this class to be replaced in the running website?

Comment: If this is a 'Web Application' as opposed to a 'Website' project the 'App_Code' Folder is actually 'App_LocalResources' folder and it will be hard to deploy a single file.

Comment: And how should i update this class, since it generates no DLL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to be in trouble if you don't deploy this correctly.

First question: Is this a Web Application Project?  I don't see how it could be if you don't have a DLL.

Therefore, we'll assume it's a Web Site project.  In that case, you should just drop the new code-behind file (or the aspx if it's inline) over the existing one.  (I shouldn't have to tell you to make a backup first)

If you drop a code file in App_Code and it duplicates a class already built in another place, you're in for trouble.  Do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

Ask someone to create an `App_Code` folder using FTP.

Comment: Does that have to be a virtual folder created through IIS, or could some questions: it simply be created through the FTP ? and if the class is currently working in there, wouldn't there be any conflicts ? Is the recognition of the existance of App_Code made through the name or should I address it somewhere else ?

Comment: The `App_Code` folder is an ordinary folder in the application root.  ASP.Net will see it automatically.

Comment: And then I put the class.vb file inside the App_Code, and it's good to go ?